# Empty response in Angular 4 from java backend

Tags: angular, spring-boot, httprequest, httpresponse, angular4-httpclient

I'm new to Angular and I have a problem. I want to get data to my graph from my spring boot backend. I send a GET request from my Angular App and I receive empty response despite seeing in the console that it is not empty. Could you help me?

My angular service

```
getChartData(): Observable<Array<ChartDataParameters>> {
  return this.http.get<Array<ChartDataParameters>> ('http://127.0.0.1:8080/currency/chartData');
}
```

and my component which uses this method

```
this.databaseService.getChartData().subscribe(d => {
  this.data_origin = d;
});

for (let i = 0; i < this.data_origin.length; i++) {
  this.data.push([this.data_origin[i].date, this.data_origin[i].prediction, this.data_origin[i].currency]);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You using `Http` or `HttpClient`?

Comment: `getChartData` is asynchronous. You're trying to read the value before it has been set in the subscribe.

Comment: i'm using HttpClient

Answer (score 1):

You should be using your data inside your `Subscription`. Also, you don't really need to create so many variables for the data that you're trying to use.

```
this.databaseService.getChartData().subscribe(d => {
  this.data_origin = d;
});

for (let i = 0; i < this.data_origin.length; i++) {
  this.data.push([this.data_origin[i].date, this.data_origin[i].prediction, this.data_origin[i].currency]);
}
```

should be

```
this.databaseService.getChartData().subscribe(d => {

  for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    this.data.push([d[i].date, d[i].prediction, d[i].currency]);
  }

});
```

Also, I think there's something wrong with what you're doing here. Is data supposed to be an array of objects with each object containing three keys, `date`, `prediction` and `currency`?

If that's the case, I think you can reduce the logic to just this:

```
this.databaseService.getChartData().subscribe(d => {

  this.data = d.map(datum => { date: datum.date, prediction: datum.prediction, currency: datum.currency })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

move  `loop` inside `subscribe`

```
this.databaseService.getChartData().subscribe(d => {
  for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    this.data.push([d[i].date, d[i].prediction, d[i].currency]);
  }
});
```